# REST assured testing for non spring dependent java projects

Tags: java, spring, rest-assured

I have a java project which has REST end points. This java project is a plugin to the main project, which has all the spring dependencies.

How can I write REST assured integration tests for my REST endpoints for the non-spring java project?

Is adding the spring dependencies under test scope is the only way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when talking about dependencies? What do you want to use from project in your integration tests?

Comment: I have set of Rest endpoints in my project. I wanted to test them independently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to execute your REST project(project) independently you can use rest assured without mock and without Spring dependencies, but in case you need you main project to have plugin one running you need the dependencies.

Also, if you want to do real-time automation testing, not a unit testing with mock, you just need to make sure you REST endpoints is up and running and then you can freely use rest assured

Comment: @krisnik if the answer is the one that you was looking please mark it as correct , thanks